# Including sidebar in Cake PHP template

Tags: php, view, cakephp-3.1

I'm trying to create a sidebar in my template but I'm getting `Cake\View\Exception\MissingElementException`. I've created `sidebar.ctp` in `/src/View/Element/` directory, and call it like this :

```
<?= $this->element('sidebar') ?>
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs a little more closely, template files belong into the `Template` directory, not the `View` directory.

See **[Cookbook > Views > Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.